# Django Rest Framework: finding model instance with url slug, not pk (lookup_field, retrievemodelmixin)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to use RetrieveModelMixin. 
Default setting is finding with pk, but I want to find a model instance with another model field.
Then, how can I do this?
I tried to add
 lookup_fields = 'usename'
but it didn't make it.

```
#models.py
    class Profile(models.Model):
    user       = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='', blank=True, null=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank = False, null = True) 
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null =True)
    introduction = models.TextField()


#serializers.py
    class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
        lookup_fields = 'username'

#urls.py
    path('test/<slug:username>/', views.ProfileDetail.as_view(),name='profiles-detail'),  


#views.py
    class ProfileDetail(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                 mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                 mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                 generics.GenericAPIView):

    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    lookup_fields = 'username'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

This results

Expected view ProfileDetail to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.

How can I fix this error?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [attributes on the view and the serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#attributes) are called `lookup_field`, not `lookup_fields`.